# Bootstrap Auto Height Panels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 panels (see image)
[image: Panel View]

`Panel1`'s height changing the height based on the content.
`Panel2` has a fixed height.
And my problem: I want for `Panel3` a "perfect" height like `height = panel1.height - panel2.height`

But I don't know how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this--

**Using javascript**

```
var panel1Height = document.getElementById('panel1').clientHeight;
var panel2Height = '20';
var panel3Height = panel1Height - panel2Height;
document.getElementById("panel3").style.height= panel3Height + 'px';
```

**note**
this is just a mock up customize it according to your needs.

Comment: The last line have to look this `document.getElementById("panel3").style.height= panel3Height + "px";`, and now its perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This framework does the work in a line `height`.. and always self-adjust if you put dynamic content

Framework: https://github.com/mattbanks/jQuery.equalHeights
code: https://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc